# A well formed java string

Tags: java, string

A friend had an interview question asking the following:

> Given a string comprising of the characters (,),{,},[,], determine if is well formed or not.

In my mind I would have answered no as it is a string and so "/" character would be required to print said characters. Is this correct or am I way off base?

Comment: You are likely to be misunderstanding the question

Comment: They're probably asking to check whether the parens match.

Comment: I don't understand the question; define "well-formed".

Comment: that is where I was bit lost. to me it was ambiguous.

Comment: What makes you think '/' character is required to print this string?

Comment: This all depends on what "well-formed" means.  I'm guessing since it is an interview question they basically wanted to see if you know how to handle "Context Free Languages".

Answer (score 7):

if well-formed means each brace is closed with a matching brace and there are no incidents like ({)}, then I would suggest you to use stack

1. go through each character in the string
2. if it is opening brace, push it on the stack
3. if it is closing brace, pop from stack and look, if it is a match
   -> if you go through all chars in string and stack is empty, your string is well formed

Comment: KISS dude. No need for stack. Just keep a counter for each pair.

Comment: by using only counters you do not ommit incidents when brace is closed by non matching one

Comment: @m0skit0 - dude a stackless algorithm cannot detect improper nesting.

Comment: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=9447750 - Similar question here with many solutions posted. Stackless solutions are both longer and more convoluted.

Comment: @moskito - try that algorithm with this `"[(])"` ... which has incorrect nesting.

Comment: @Isaac - the problem you linked to is simpler.  This one involves 3 types of bracketing.  It is qualitatively different.

Comment: @JanHruby you're right, my bad.

Comment: @StephenC in fact my solution cannot even detect this much simpler sequence correctly `)()(` as pointed out by Jan.

Comment: @m0skit0 - no hard feelings, at first look I was thinking stackless too;)

Comment: @m0skit0 - Actually, if you check for the counter going negative as well as to zero, then a counter-based checker *should* work ... for that example.

Comment: @StephenC yup, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking what the interview question means.

The answer is that is means what the interviewer meant it to mean.  You (or your friend) should ask the interviewer for clarification if you need it.  (Indeed, if you *didn't* ask the interviewer for clarification, you might "lose points" ... for not asking.)

However, a reasonable interpretation would be that the question is asking the interviewee to write a method to check that a String consisting of those characters has balanced bracketing; e.g.

```
    []{[]}    OK
    [         BAD
    [(])      BAD
```

---

FWIW - there is no general definition for a "well-formed string".  Rather a string is considered to be well-formed with respect to some grammar, if a valid parse tree can be constructed for the string using the productions of the grammar.

The problem in this case is that no such grammar has been provided (at least, not here).  Hence the interview question (as stated) is incomplete / ambiguous / only answerable if you are prepared to *guess* what grammar the interviewer means.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is "exactly what do you mean by well formed?"  Vague requirements should be made more specific, and that's a signal that you are looking for correct functionality, not a quick fix.

We can guess as to what it means.  It might mean correct nesting of elements, such that opening and closing parenthesis follow an xml-style tag syntax, where

```
{([)]}
```

would not be well formed

It might mean properly escaped so that it can be printed in an environment where the characters are interpreted as commands.  In such a case, well formed might mean

```
\{\(\[
```

It might even mean that once an opening character is found, the only following legal character is its closing character.  In such a case, the following would not be well formed.

```
{()}
```

If well formed just means one closing item for each opening item, then (due to the definition) the following even might be ok

```
)(
```

In short, when you have doubt, ask.  Asking is the key to so many things, and it shows that you are paying attention and thinking.  These skills are far more important than "knowing the answer" because knowing the answer without understanding the request results in answering the wrong question.

Comment: Also, asking is the key to getting a cooperative effort between you and your interviewer.  It's good to interact with the people who might hire you, as they learn more about you (which helps them select you from a pool of unknowns) and you learn more about them (which helps you avoid the shops that will make your life miserable)